# Oracle query execution hangs and not getting result in java

Tags: java, oracle

If query execution takes a long time then the result is not coming to the Java layer. if we run the query in Oracle SQL developer there the query getting timed out. If anybody can help with this then its great.

Comment: I guess you know how to debug and add a debug point where the db layer is being called and see it hangs on the same point

Comment: yes i tried that but now the query is getting timed out in sql developer too

Comment: if the sql dev tool times out then there is no way you can do it with java. could you also run the cost calculation in the tool. so you can analyze which part takes too much time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things can happen,

1) In your java layer it takes too much time to process those db results to actual pojos. You might think like results are not coming but most of the time it takes too long to process those data. Because same query get executed really fast in oracle dev tools.

2) Oracle has [locks](https://gerardnico.com/data/concurrency/lock) and maybe some other thread or a request from a web application is holding on to a database record so the entire process waits for the table or row to get finished.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but after checking once again in sql developer the query is timed out after 1 hr

Comment: if the sql dev tool times out then there is no way you can do it with java. could you also run the cost calculation in the tool. so you can analyze which part takes too much time